# Getting a list printed 2 times in python, don't know why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried the below code, but it is printing the list 2 times, one is incorrect output and second output is correct. Can't find out what is wrong with the code, any help is appreciated.

code:

```
nums = [2,7,15,11]
target = 18
# Output should be a list that shows indices of numbers that add up to target.

Output = []
for i in range(len(nums)):
    t = target - nums[i]
    if t in nums:
        u = nums.index(t)
        Output.append(u)
Output.sort()
print(Output)
```

Comment: You have one `print` in this code.

Comment: Thanks Guy for your quick reply, I am getting below as output:
[0]
[1, 3]
the first [0] should not be there ideally? or am I missing something?

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: your codes give ONE output of `[1, 3]` I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: The `[0]` is not from the code you posted. I'm getting only `[1, 3]`.

Comment: Are you writing this in jupyter notebook or any notebook and output would have been like Out [0]: [1, 3]. Because I too got only [1,3] as output

Comment: seems some issue with visual studio, coz in other IDLE its giving only [1, 3], thanks all!